# Tesseract OCR in osX application

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on an os X application, in which I would like to use Tesseract.

I found a lot of sample codes for iOS applications, like [here](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/), but not for os X applications.

The problem seems to be the architecture (different in iOS and os X ?) :

```
    ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jerrycor3/Desktop/tesseract-ios-master/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/liblept.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jerrycor3/Desktop/tesseract-ios-master/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/liblept.a (3 slices)ignoring file /Users/jerrycor3/Desktop/tesseract-ios-master/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/libtesseract_all.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jerrycor3/Desktop/tesseract-ios-master/tesseract-ios-lib/lib/libtesseract_all.a (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "STRING::STRING(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract initEngine] in Tesseract.o
  "STRING::STRING(STRING const&)", referenced from:
      GenericVector<STRING>::clear() in Tesseract.o
  "STRING::STRING()", referenced from:
```

Do you know any sample code or tutorial which explain how to use Tesseract in os X please ?